# Entity Framework Include performance problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include

Good Morning,
I have a problem with the performance if i use include.

Have a look at the following query, if I load the data from the include (x.Server_Item.itemType) the query needs like 980ms.
If i remove them, the query needs 51ms.

980ms:

```
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    var items = db.Characters_Inventory
               .Where(x => x.charId == charId && x.itemLocation == ItemLocationInventory)
               .Include(p => p.Server_Items)
               .AsSplitQuery()
               .Select(x => new
    {
        itemId = x.id,
        x.itemName,
        x.nameTag,
        x.itemAmount,
        x.itemLocation,
        x.isItemEquipped,
        x.itemCategory,
        x.metaId,
        x.metaTag0,
        x.metaTag1,
        itemType = x.Server_Items.itemType,
        itemSubType = x.Server_Items.itemSubType,
        itemClothesType = x.Server_Items.Server_Clothes.type,
        itemPicName = x.Server_Items.itemPicSRC,
        itemWeight = x.Server_Items.itemWeight,
        itemGender = x.Server_Items.Server_Clothes.gender,
        isItemUseable = x.Server_Items.isItemUseable,
        isItemDroppable = x.Server_Items.isItemDroppable,
        isItemGiveable = x.Server_Items.isItemGiveable,
        isItemStorable = x.Server_Items.isItemStorable,
        isItemStackable = x.Server_Items.isItemStackable,
        isItemShowable = x.Server_Items.isItemShowable,
        isItemNameable = x.Server_Items.isItemNameable,
        isItemPlaceable = x.Server_Items.isItemPlaceable,
        //isClothesTypeEquipped = IsClothesTypeEquipped(charId, x.id),
        isClothesSwitchable = x.Server_Items.Server_Clothes.altClothesName != "" ? true : false
        //isWeaponTypeEquipped = IsWeaponTypeEquipped(charId, x.id),
        //charName = Characters.GetCharacterName(x.metaId)
    }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
}
```

50ms:

```
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    var items = db.Characters_Inventory
                .Where(x => x.charId == charId && x.itemLocation == ItemLocationInventory)
                .Include(p => p.Server_Items)
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .Select(x => new
    {
        itemId = x.id,
        x.itemName,
        x.nameTag,
        x.itemAmount,
        x.itemLocation,
        x.isItemEquipped,
        x.itemCategory,
        x.metaId,
        x.metaTag0,
        x.metaTag1
    }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
}
```

I tried with AsSplitQuery and without AsSplitQuery.

Maybe nice to know: On the included table (Server_Items) is alrdy a table included.

Thanks in advance.
Sincerely

Comment: You're comparing the difference between getting data from one table vs getting the data from 3 tables, why do you think the performance should be the same? Have you checked the query against the server directly? Have you checked the number of rows, the indexes used, etc?

Comment: The comments are absolutely on point; in the "faster" query you don't actually pull any data out of the related tables, so sqlserver can already start planning to not bother doing some IO, and the queries request different things; the "slow" query requires a join to Server_Clothes, implicit from the isClothesSwitchable retrieval.. The second query could get faster still, as the Include is useless, but if it causes a join that results in repetition of values in Characters_Inventory resultset, it means more data to transport and then EF's got to dedupe it..

Comment: i added now the indexes... that was a great affort. server to server from 650ms to 13ms.
Otherside: 980ms to 70-130ms.
Do i have to add somethin to the modelbuilder for this indexed?

Comment: Easiest thing, if you make a DB side change like that, scaffold it again and run a diff tool on your newly scaff'd context versus your current one. Installing EF Core Power Tools extension makes re-scaffing to a new folder a few mouse clicks of a job

Comment: You can define an index in the model builder using `entity.HasIndex(e => e.Prop).HasName("");` or `entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Prop1, e.Prop2});`

Comment: You can also include additional properties `entity.HasIndex(e => e.Prop1)
                .IncludeProperties(e => new { e.Prop2, e.Prop2}).HasName("");`

Comment: Thank you Connell, but do i need this if I use indexes on databaselevel?